# Odoo in stock quant lot_id column sorting wrong by clicking on column name

Tags: python, sorting, odoo

I have one column that don't appear to be sorting correctly.  I can't sort by serial number by clicking on column name. It appears sorting random. Talking about other columns like quantity or product_creation_date or product everything is alright I can sort desc/asc by clicking on quantity or product_creation_date columns.

I can't find what's wrong..

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_stock_quant_splius_tree">
    <field name="name">stock.quant.splius.tree</field>
    <field name="model">stock.quant</field>
    <field eval="1" name="priority"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Quants" create="0" delete="0">
            <field name="location_id"/>
            <field name="product_id"/>
            <field name="qty"/>
            <field name="product_uom_id" string="Uom"/>
            <field name="lot_id"/>
            <field name="in_date"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

[sorting by clicking on column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMg9.png)

Comment: It is possible if and only if we can use the order attribute on stock.quant model other wise u must have do some more customization on tree view (list view)

Comment: Yep the problem was that in stock.quant model core code there was no attribute _order. So I extend model with attribute _order. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I know well, you can not sort relation fields (o2m, m2o, m2m).